# Apollo: Call a mutation server-side from cron job?

Tags: meteor, graphql, apollo

I have a Meteor app that uses Apollo and I am using SyncedCron (https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) to schedule an update operation on the database every 2 hours.

Every two hours, fetch X data from some external API and store in Y collection of the database. Rinse and repeat.

My question is this: should this update operation be implemented as a graphQL mutation, and called server-side from within the cron job (if so, how do you do it?!), or should this be implemented as a normal JS function since it will only ever execute on the server?

All the mutation examples I can find online are invoked from the client by wrapping your View component in a graphql-enabled HOC.

Perhaps I am just misunderstanding the scope of mutations, and the larger question here is whether or not mutations *CAN* be invoked from the server, or if they are client-side only.

Hoping to find some clarification here on mutation best practices. Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you would just use axios (http call) or a meteor method here. I think mutations are just for browser-to-server.