# Apollo GraphQL: Call a Mutation from the Server?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I need to call a mutation from a cron job running on the server. [I found this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172332/apollo-call-a-mutation-server-side-from-cron-job), but the accepted answer said there was no way to do it.

[Then I found this on GitHub, from 2017](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/289):

> `graphql-server` is a network wrapper for `graphql core` function. if you
> don't want to use it over network, you can just run it standalone:
>
> ```
> import scheme from './scheme';
>
> const query = `{
>   me {
>     name   
>   }
> }`;
>
> const result = graphql(scheme, query);
> console.log(result);
> ```
>
> function documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/graphql.js#L19)

That looks pretty good! Is that the best practices approach in 2020?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out about this approach as well. It's possible to create an Apollo client directly on the server.

```
export const getApolloServerClient = () =>

  new ApolloClient({

    ssrMode: true,

    cache: new InMemoryCache(),

    link: new SchemaLink({ schema }),

  });
```

Comment: Careful with this approach. In the browser, the cache is deleted every time you navigate away or refresh the page. On the server, the cache wouldn't be deleted until the process is restarted. That means you pretty much always want to bypass the cache by using a `network-only` policy for your calls to `ApolloClient.query`. It's also worth noting that, without caching, you're not really getting anything out of using ApolloClient other than added overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have access to the `GraphQLSchema` object used by your GraphQL server, then the simplest approach is to just use the [graphql](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/graphql/#graphql) function exported by the `graphql` module. Note that you should await the returned Promise to access the result:

```
async function run () {
  const { data, errors } = await graphql(
    schema, 
    query,
    rootValue,
    context,
    variables
  )
}
```

However, you can also make requests to the server itself over the network -- if the server is on the same host, you'd just use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. In that case, you can use `axios`, `request` or any other HTTP client library in a Node.js script. You can also just use `curl` to make the request directly in a bash script or curl command.

Comment: Hi, how would you actually call the server with this? I am wanting to call a mutation via a github action which calls my apollo-server-express backend but I assume I cant just sent this to the IP of the server? I can see the request hitting my server but the mutation is never called.